# How to read range of cells using column=numbers instead of letters in OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I know I can read range of cells using that code:

```
worksheet.cell(range="A1:J1").value
```

but I prefer to use numbers instead of letters to select columns, something like that:

```
worksheet.cell(row=1,column=1:10).value
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ws.cell()` can only return individual cells so ranges for it make no sense. To access a range of cells you can use `ws.iter_rows()` or `ws.rows` or `ws.columns`. Upto and including version 2.3 `ws.iter_rows()` only accepts Excel-style range notation but you can use row and column offsets to create a range. Starting with version 2.4 you will be able to provide fully numerical (1-based indexing) values for `min_row`, `min_col`, `max_row` and `max_col`.

Comment: Single cell access example for A1: `ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'test'`

Comment: Aside from iter_rows, it seems like there should be a single method (ws.cells) that can provides range comprehension by truth tests args to determine if someone wants a row, col, cell, or range.  ie  `if row=None, col=7: return ws.columns[7]`.  Perhaps once I become competent at unit testing I could help with this...

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure `worksheet.cell(range="A1:J1").value` is possible?

The above may be possible using `range` function as given in the official documentation:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html

> There are 2 ways to use worksheet.cell:
>
> Usage: cell(coodinate=’A15’) or cell(row=15, column=1)
>
> If coordinates are not given, then row and column must be given.

So, you can use a list comprehension:

```
data = [worksheet.cell(row=1,column=i).value for i in range(1,11)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to read this data! For example

```
type(sheet['A7':'B8'])
```

will give you `<class 'tuple'>`, by typing

```
type(sheet['A7':'B8'][i])
```

where i=1,2, you will get the same type. Therefore it is a tuple of tuples. It has as many tuple as the number of rows in the range.

I define a function with the start-end indeices of the row-column range as its arguments and returning a similar tuple of tuples but having values of the cells inside.
You can similarly define your own function with a different type of output and any information that you want to extract.

```
def RangeValue(a, b, c, d):
    return(tuple(tuple(sheet.cell(row=a+i, column=c+j).value for j in range(d-c+1)) for i in range(b-a+1)))
```

Now for the range A7:B8, you just need to ask `RangeValue(7,8,1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to break a range into rows and store the cell values of each row in a tuple or list. There are 2 methods that are clean and easy for this:

**Assumptions:**

ws: worksheet e.g. `ws=wb['Sheet1']`

rng: any range in ws e.g. `rng=ws['A1':'D10']` or `rng=ws['A1':'D' + str(ws.max_column)]`

**Method 1:**

`t=tuple(rng)`

this will return a tuple that contains tuples of each row. So in this example, t will have 10 tuples and each inner tuple will have 4 elements/values.

**Method 2:**

```
final_list=[]
for row in rng:
    mylist=list(row)
    final_list.append(mylist)
```

this will be pretty much the same thing except instead of tuples you would have lists.

**NOTE:**

list of lists or tuple of tuples will store `cells` and not their values, so to access their value do this:

```
first_cell_value=t[0][0].value
```